# Anybody still making inkjet printers with parallel port interfaces?

Tags: printer, printing, parallel-port

I need small inkjet printers with parallel port interfaces.  Unfortunately, it looks like all the big manufacturers have moved fully to USB and ethernet/wireless.

Adapters won't work.  These are for integrated systems that do not have USB and cannot be upgraded.

Anybody have a source for buying older printers, perhaps?  HP preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a USB to Parallel Converter?

Comment: Wrong direction.  It would have to be a Parallel to USB converter.  I don't even think that conversion would be possible.

Comment: Actually, they do exist.
http://www.epapersign.com/LPT-to-USB/parallel-to-usb-connector/

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is *inkjet*. You can get any number of impact printers that still have parallel ports. You can also buy plenty of nicer laser printers with parallel ports (I'm assuming [IEEE 1284](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284)).

But inkjets are, by and large, crappy, throw-away printers. It's going to be hard to find something in that niche, and even if you do, you're going to have trouble with consumables...I can still buy loose toner and loose developer for an 18 year old laser printer, but ink cartridges for an inkjet old enough to be parallel? Maybe not.

I'd recommend getting slightly better printers. Check the [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) supported by your legacy app: that can be a headache.

@boden: Ahh, you've got a size limitation. What are the dimensions?

Comment: I've got 15 year old HP inkjets that we can still get cartridges for.  I looked into laser and can't find anything small enough.  See, the printer actually has to fit inside of the device.

Answer (score 1):

They don't still make them with parallel port interfaces cheaply, but you can still get the [HP Business Inkjet 2800dtn](http://www.shopping.hp.com/product/printer/inkjet/1/storefronts/C8164A%2523A2L) which has one.